# Is it possible to include a table name in a select query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add a Table Name for audit purposes, for example if I am running a query:

```
Select TableA, sum(col1), sum(col1), count(*) As rowcount
from TableA
```

However there is no such column `Name` in the table as `TableA`, but is there anyway to bring it in to the query somehow? For example using sys tables or information schema and bring the table name in that way?

Also I am doing a whole host of tables like for example from `TableA` to `TableH`
how can I do that for each table using TSQL?

Thank you

Comment: Sure. Just make it a string literal. 'TableA'

Answer (score 1):

You can add a string, one that happens to match the table name.  This requires single quotes:

```
Select 'TableA' as tablename, sum(col1), sum(col1), count(*) As rowcount
from TableA;
```

If you want to do this in a more canonical way, you would need dynamic SQL.

```
declare @tablename varchar(255);
set @tablename = 'tableA';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'Select '@tablename' as tablename, sum(col1), sum(col1), count(*) As rowcount
    from @tablename';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@tablename', @tablename);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

This is the basic code.  You would need a `while` loop to go through all the tables you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you but is there a way to do it dynamically using for all tables from TableA through TableH

Comment: How would the loop look like sorry? Never had to use Loops before

Comment: Actually I put the names of all the tables in table, how would the sql go like to loop through each recordset?

Comment: @abs786123 Why did you put the names of all the tables in a table? They are already in  sys.tables. There are thousands of `WHILE` loop examples out there... Google "While loop SQL Server"

Comment: @abs786123: This sounds wrong. In a database you have the entities you are dealing with in tables, e.g. items and orders and suppliers, or persons and addresses and jobs, whatever. If it's table names you are storing that suggests you are writing a DBMS that deals with tables, columns, constraints etc. I guess, however, you are not writing a DBMS :-)

Comment: @abs786123: Then, as mentioned, a table contains an entity, say items or orders or suppliers. To loop dynamically through tables to show sums of two particular columns that you expect to be present in all those tables (?) seems to indicate the tables all contain the same entity (e.g. all orders), only somehow separated (e.g. by year). If that is the case: Don't do that. Have one table instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- You can use Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables to table infor
-- Or just define the targeted tables
Declare @Tables table (TableName varchar(100))
Insert Into @Tables values
('TableA'),
('TableB'),
('TableC'),
('TableD'),
('TableE'),
('TableF'),
('TableG'),
('TableH')

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @SQL = Replace(@SQL+'Union All'+char(13)+'Select TableName='''+TableName+''',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From '+TableName+char(13),'>>>union all','')
 From  @Tables

Exec(@SQL)
```

The SQL Generated is

```
Select TableName='TableA',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableA
Union All
Select TableName='TableB',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableB
Union All
Select TableName='TableC',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableC
Union All
Select TableName='TableD',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableD
Union All
Select TableName='TableE',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableE
Union All
Select TableName='TableF',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableF
Union All
Select TableName='TableG',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableG
Union All
Select TableName='TableH',Col1=sum(col1), Col2=sum(col), [RowCount]=count(*) From TableH
```

Comment: Thank you, but came back with error -  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RowCount'.

Comment: @abs786123 Sorry RowCount is reserved changed to [RowCount].  See updated